# Make images in a text clickable in React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, lightbox

I'm building a website where I get a blog post from an API call. The body of the post is just html code mixed with text, images and even objects like `youtube` videos (it is build with ckeditor in the back). Everything is working as expected but I would like to make images clickable. Clicking the image, would open a modal in lightbox style.

I was considering extracting all the images (if any) from the body and making a gallery at the bottom of the post. But I think that would be more elegant just making images clickable and opening the dialag without showing them twice along the post.

An example of the response:

```
body: "<p>this is a text with some images: <img src='path/to/image1' /> and <img src='path/to/image2' /> how to make them clickable in React?</p>"
```

That body is rendered this way:

```
<GridItem xs={12} sm={8} md={8}>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />
</GridItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onClick event in your image:

`<img src='path/to/image2' onClick={() => {aFunction}} />`

ps: if you want to, you can add a ***className*** to put a ***cursor:pointer*** too.

Comment: but how? that image is a string mixed with html and other images

Comment: you can use javascript to filter your string and set it to a variable. 
Once you have the image link in your variable, you can treat it, and therefore set this variable as a SRC to your IMG tag

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you
first of all, you need to cover the content of blog post (returned HTML from API call) into one single wrapper div.
after that, you can need to get all the elements of blog post using javascript like the example below

```
const elements = document.getElementById("wrapper").elements
```

now you can iterate throw all elements in blog post including the images

```
elements.forEach(item => {
   if (item.type == "img")
    // do this
})
```

I will edit the second code example in a few minutes